# Issue with permitted_uri_chars in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I am facing issue with permitted_uri_chars in CodeIgniter. Followig is my config:

> $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_-()@!';

As per my config the Special Symbols should be allowed. It work for symbols but when I use the Symbols in combination it don't work.

Scenario:

> `http://localhost/ci/test/index/page(new).html`

When my URL as above i am getting the error:

```
An Error Was Encountered

The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.
```

But following works fine.

```
http://localhost/ci/test/index/page(new.html

http://localhost/ci/test/index/pagenew).html
```

How can I solve this issue? I don't wish to solve this issue using .htaccess !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@TomPHP Please put the below characters in your `config.php` file.

`$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-()@!';`

You forgot to put `\` in allowing character that raise issue for uri.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this. works for me.

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-()@!';
```